# jQuery DataTables: Get checkbox value from specific column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and trying to retrieve if checkboxes are checked for all rows of a specific column.  This is an attempt to set up custom filtering based on different column values.  Here is a little code example:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex){
    //var checkedFilters = Here I get any of my checkboxes out side of datatables that im using to filter.

     if(checkedFilters.length{
         result = false;
       $(checkedFilters).each(function(i, obj){
           var $value = '';
           var $column = 0;

              switch(obj){
                  case 'Monday':  
                  case 'Tuesday':
                  case 'Wednesday':
                  etc, etc.:
                     $value = $obj;
                     $column = aData[4]; //This works fine for getting data that is NOT a checkbox
                     break;
                  case 'Disabled': // This one is a column of checkbox values
                     $value = true or checked, or however i need to compare the data;
                     $column = aData[17];  //unable to get at the state of the checkbox this way.   
                     break;

                }

                if ($column === $value) {
                        result = true;
                        return false;
                    }


                return result;

                if(!checkedFilters.length){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

I appreciate your help!   Thank you!

This is the html displayed for column 17:

```
<td id="isDisabled">   //Checked
     <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled"       type="checkbox" />
</td>

<td id="isDisabled">  //Un-checked
   <input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
</td>
```

Comment: Can please you add `console.log(aData[17])` after `case 'Disabled':` and post the results?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com  Thank you for responding.  The data is coming back blank when using aData[] on column 17.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing on this one is updating my view model to take a string value instead of a boolean checkbox value.   So now when I query the database, I convert the value to string "True" or "False"...   This way I can read the values the same way I am for the Monday - Sunday values:

```
if(checkedFilters.length{
     result = false;
   $(checkedFilters).each(function(i, obj){
       var $value = '';
       var $column = 0;

          switch(obj){
              case 'Monday':  
              case 'Tuesday':
              case 'Wednesday':
              etc, etc.:
                 $value = $obj;
                 $column = aData[4]; //This works fine for getting data that is NOT a checkbox
                 break;
              case 'Disabled': // Converted this from boolean to string "True" or "False"
                 $value = "True"
                 $column = aData[17];  // Now returns "True" or "False"
                 break;
            }

            if ($column === $value) {
                    result = true;
                    return false;
                }


            return result;

            if(!checkedFilters.length){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I had to spend 10 or so more minutes updating my view model, but I didn't have to do anything else extra.  I hope this helps anyone else who runs into this.